# Azure analysis Service Cube process status from Log Analytics

Tags: ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I am trying to get all azure analysis services cube process status from Log analytics, using below KQL on Log analytics but getting zero records always.

Can you please help which Log analytics table and columns gives status of cube process.?

```
let sessionIdInProgress = aas_engine
| where ['time'] > ago(1d)
//and operationName == 'ProgressReportBegin'
and  operationName == 'ProgressReportEnd'
| summarize by SessionID
| project SessionID;

aas_engine
| where ['time'] >ago(1d)
and SessionID !in ( sessionIdInProgress )
and operationName == 'ProgressReportCurrent'
| extend endTime = now()
| extend durationInHours = datetime_diff('hour', endTime, StartTime)
| extend durationInMinutes = datetime_diff('minute', endTime, StartTime)
| project SessionID, StartTime, durationInMinutes, durationInHours, operationName, resourceId
```

Thanks,
Brahma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reached Microsoft support team and they helped me to get Azure Analysis Service Cube process status from Log analytics.

Below is sample KQL:

```
let CompletedConnectionID = aas_engine
| where ['time'] > ago(10h)
and EventClass == 'COMMAND_END' 
and TextData contains "RefreshType"
| summarize by ConnectionID
| project ConnectionID;

let CubeProcessActiveAAS = aas_engine
| where ['time'] > ago(10h)
and EventClass == 'COMMAND_BEGIN' 
and TextData contains "RefreshType"
and ConnectionID !in ( CompletedConnectionID )
| extend EndTime1 = case(isnull(EndTime), now(), EndTime )
| extend Status = case(isnull(EndTime), 'Inprogress', 'Completed' )
| extend durationInMinutes = datetime_diff('minute', EndTime1, StartTime)
| summarize by ServerName, StartTime,durationInMinutes,Status,ConnectionID
```